# DYMO 4xl missing Cups share and local folders

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

I am trying to install DYMO and it assumes that cups is installed at the following folders:

- '/usr/local/lib/cups'
- '/usr/local/share/cups'

But it seems after a fresh install Cups is only installed at `/etc/cups` 20.04

So, I assume I need to add these folders and files to the above locations?

https://www.dymo-label-printers.co.uk/news/download-dymo-sdk-for-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I needed to install the cups libs cups basically:

```
sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev libcupsimage2-dev gcc g++
```

However the best easiest way to install the printer:

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-dymo
```